# Using javascript to validate a user control in a gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am new to javascript, and I would like to use it to validate a user control in a gridview (radgrid listview).

This is what I had done so far, but the javascript is not firing.

I don't want to use the Range validator as the validator error message takes some space even when not displayed and it does not look good in my gridview.

Thank you in advance for your help

Anne

**HTML Code:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="sks_Creation.ascx.cs" Inherits="Sapphire.Control.Assessment.sks_Creation" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {
            var grid = document.getElementById("<%= LV.ClientID%>");
        for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {

            var Mark = $("input[id*=txtMark]")
            var ValMark = $("input[id*=lblValMark]")

            if (Mark == 0) {
                alert("Mark should be greater than 0");
                ValMark = "Mark should be greater than 0";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<tlk:RadListView ID="LV" runat="server" Width="99%" OnNeedDataSource="LV_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="LV_ItemDataBound" AllowPaging="true" ItemPlaceholderID="QuestionContainer">

    <ItemTemplate>
         <fieldset style="border: none;">

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="SelectedCQLVRow" >
                <tr>
                    <td>

            <asp:Label ID="lblQuestion" CssClass="CQPanelQuestion" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' visible="false"/>

                   <hrz:TextBox ID="txtMark" Text='<%# Eval("Mark") %>' runat="server" LabelText="Mark" />
                   <asp:Label ID="lblValMark" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />

            <div class="CQBottomRight"  >
                <tlk:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" ToolTip="Save this question" Text="Save" Visible='<%# Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsEnabled").ToString()) %>'
                CommandName="SaveGVQuestion" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QID")%>' OnCommand="btn_ClickEvent" OnClientClick="validate()" 
                skin="Metro" Height="25px" Width="80px"> 
                    <Icon SecondaryIconCssClass="rbSave" SecondaryIconLeft="4" SecondaryIconTop="3"></Icon>
                </tlk:RadButton>
            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
   </ItemTemplate>
</tlk:RadListView>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking, so this isn't in the answer section, but if you set the RangeValidator Display attribute to "Dynamic" it will only take up space when it is visible

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for your comment, but I would like to be able to do it in javascript.